# Back Up Data Files From SSD Drive When Boot Drive Has Been Accidently Deleted

Tags: boot, usb

I accidentally deleted boot drive /dev/sda when trying to clear a USB drive which would not mount although detected. (I entered /dev/sda rather than /dev/sdb ...)

Online it says that all that needs doing is to boot from some CD or USB, then run:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda 
sudo update-grub 
sudo reboot
```

But all my unbacked up data folders are also on the affected SSD drive, so I'd feel better if I could back these up prior to making any all or nothing gamble with the boot drive.

I've already got back onto the machine using a separate version of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS that is on a USB drive. Although this USB system can see the SSD drive and its capacity, it does not distinguish the folders inside it so I can't just copy and paste them out. (I was surprised by this as I used to have a Manjaro on a USB drive that could see individual folders and files when run on a Windows system.)

Is there any way I can recover these folders using the second Ubuntu system on the USB drive ?

**EDIT**

@Nmath I can't be 100% sure, but the readme inside memtest gives this command to reclaim USB drive space - though I had /sda instead of /sdb.
No warnings were shown and no bad effects were noticed till the machine was restarted the next day.

```
For Linux/Mac:

1) Insert the USB drive into a USB slot.
2) Determine which device the USB drive is assigned as (eg. /dev/sdc on Linux, /dev/disk1 on Mac).
3) As root, use the 'dd' command to erase the partition table of the USB drive. For example,

dd if=/dev/zero of=<dev> bs=512 count=1

where <dev> is the device the USB key is assigned to. Use the base device (ie. /dev/sdc) not a partition designation (ie. /dev/sdc1).
```

I also tried these commands to mount the USB drive that I did not see:

```
sudo  mkdir /media/usb-drive

sudo mount /dev/sda /media/usb-drive
```

@oldfred :

```
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.
Disk /dev/sda: 500118192 sectors, 238.5 GiB
Model: SanDisk X400 2.5
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 1273BDE1-C928-4017-9B39-34DCD4743F1C
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 500118158
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 500118125 sectors (238.5 GiB)
```

Comment: "*when trying to clear a USB drive*" - What *exactly* did you do? AFAIK, "clear" is not an action you can apply to a flash drive.  Did you format the disk containing the root file system?  Because that overwrites the part of the drive that makes sense of the file system. It's kind of like ripping all the pages out of a book, putting them through the shredder and throwing it up in the air. Most of the data is still probably there, but that doesn't mean you'll recover it. Backups are supposed to happen *before* you lose data, not after

Comment: If writing an ISO, it only overwrites the beginning of the drive. And if gpt partitioned then you may still have backup partition table. But if zeroing out entire drive all your data may be gone. What does this show? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` if drive is sda.

Comment: @oldfred See edit to question

Comment: No gpt data, so drive was totally erased or was not gpt and beginning of drive where MBR(msdos) partition table was is gone. Only if you did not totally overwrite everything may testdisk find old partition tables or photorec be able to recovery something. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk & http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step & http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

Comment: @oldfred Why did the system not pop-up a warning - as it does for so many more trivial actions ? Any point in trying sudo grub-install /dev/sda, etc ?

Comment: If you used dd to erase drive, there is no warning. If you just installed grub to MBR, that would not erase drive. What exactly did you do?

Comment: @oldfred I can't say I know exactly which command blew away access/visibility of the SDD drive contents - the likely suspects are listed in my EDIT to the question above. But I was just asking if the command set listed at the start of my question would be worth a try in aid of recovery ?

Comment: Did you update UEFI and it changed drive back to Intel RST or RAID. Windows updates also do that.

Comment: @oldfred I did update the BIOS lately to this one https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ie/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=khpvm&oscode=wt64a&productcode=inspiron-15-5567-laptop  and I had no problems booting up.The **memtest** download I did required a UEFI-capable system. But the boot was working fine after this, I rebooted 2-3 times at least afterwards. It was after my efforts to clear and reformat a second USB I'd used for **memtest** that the boot-fail occurred, i.e. putting /dev/sda instead of /dev/sdb. I also got rid of snap directories as I preferred to use apt only.